# Variance for arbitrary power of log normal variate

Tags: distributions, lognormal-distribution

Say we have a R.V. called $X$ and let $\ln{X} \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, therefore $X$ follows a Log Normal distribution. Then let another R.V. $Y = X^{\gamma}$, where $\gamma$ is just a constant. Does $Y$ follows a specific distribution? In particular how can we calculate the variance/mean or even higher moments of Y?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X\sim \text{lognormal}$ then $X^\gamma$ is also lognormal.

The easy way to see it is to work on the log-scale; raising to a power goes to multiplication by a constant, and linear transformations of normals are normal.

Let $Z\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Let $X=e^Z$. Then, say, $Y=X^\gamma$ so $W=\log(Y) = \log({(e^Z)}^\gamma) = \gamma Z$ and the parameters of the resulting normal for $W$ are straightforward to calculate; and then standard results for the lognormal (say from the MGF for the normal) can be used to give you any moments of $Y$ you need.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a Finance grad student and I was working on deriving expected utility from a power utility function whose argument follows a log normal distribution.